# Intuition behind the definition of "Support" in Forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am reading "Characterization of generic extensions of models of set theory" in https://cmuc.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/pdf/cmuc1703/bukovsky.pdf.

*Definition 1*: For a relation r, let  $ r''a \iff $ { $ y \in rng(r) : (\exists x ∈ a) <x, y> \in r $ } [so presumably this is like a Valuation using a]

*Definition 2*: M[a] is the smallest inner model such that M ⊆ M[a] and a ∈ M[a].

*Definition 3*: The definition of **support** arises in Section 3 :

"A set σ ⊆ M is a **support** over M if for any relations $r_1, r_2 \in M$ there exists
a relation r ∈ M such that $r''σ = r''_1 σ$ \ $r''_2 σ .$

If $x = r''σ, r \in M \text{ then x } \in M[σ]$.

If N = M [G], where G is an ultrafilter on a partially ordered set generic
over M , then G is a support over M . Actually, for every x ⊆ M , x ∈ M [G], there
exists a relation r ∈ M , such that x = r'' G. If G is an ultrafilter on a complete
Boolean algebra, then for any such x even $x = f^{−1}(G)$ for some function $f \in M$ ."

**So the question is : What is the intuition behind the definition of **support** ?**

[I can see that G is intended to intersect all dense sets D, which can be viewed as sets with a relation:

$r_D$:={ $<x,y> : x \in P \land y \leq x$}.

Also whenever there is $ r''_1 σ$ \ $r''_2 σ $ then a representation of negation comes to mind, so $ P $ \ $G $ could be constructed from some object $ r \in M$, but there must be much more to it ....]

Comment: Let me just point out that this use of "support" is very particular to Bukovsky's proof.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila : A very particular and likeable transfer of the meaning of Support to Set Theory ! It may well be that to ensure P\G has an $r \in M$ the definition of support is needed. Since G isn't known in M, then Support needs to 'go over the top' to ensure a new element G is created. The proof also uses $r \subseteq P \times M$ instead of the usual P-Names. So Support could be interpreted as "there will definitely exist a "P-name equivalent r $\in M$" for P\G to ensure the proof of $ G \notin M$ goes through".

Comment: Well, I mentioned that since symmetric extensions will often have some inherent notion of "support" as well as iterated/product forcing will have an inherent notion of "support" (which may or may not differ from that of the symmetric extensions). So the term is used widely to mean different things in different contexts, and the title of the question makes it seem as though you might be expecting this term to be universally familiar.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila : Also the intersection of all dense sets should result from the Support definition (though I haven't got that far in the Bukovsky paper yet). 

[Indeed I just saw that there is Theorem 3 (P. Vopenka and B. Balcar). If $\sigma$ ⊆ M is a support, then M[$\sigma$] is a generic extension of M. Moreover, if $\sigma$ ⊆ P for some P ∈ M, |P|$^M$ < $\sigma$, then M[$\sigma$] is a $\sigma$-generic extension].

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila, Ah, finally I get your point now, thanks for persevering with me.... So Support could have lots of context specific definitions. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, typo in my comment :@Asaf Karagila : Also the intersection of all dense sets should result from the Support definition (though I haven't got that far in the Bukovsky paper yet). 

[Indeed I just saw that there is Theorem 3 (P. Vopenka and B. Balcar). If $\sigma$ ⊆ M is a support, then M[$\sigma$] is a generic extension of M. Moreover, if $\sigma$ ⊆ P for some P ∈ M, |P|$^M$ < $\kappa$ then M[$\sigma$] is a $\kappa$ -generic extension].